# How to remove all whitespace characters from the Stack/Queue

Tags: java, stack, queue

I have this FIFO Stack/Queue.

[ , , , , , , , , , Readln, A,]

all of which the leading stacks are whitespace/space characters

What i want is to remove all the whitespace characters and just have the
[Readln, A,] as my stack.

This is my code to add current string to stack and removes the character if its a whitespace but it doesnt work, also tried many other iterations aside form this, but I can't get it right. :(

Below is the last code I tried that still didn't give me what I want.

```
myQ.add(temp);
                if(myQ.peek()==" ")
                {
                    myQ.poll();
                }
```

Comment: `myQ.peek().equals(" ")`

Comment: when comparing strings you must use .equals method and not the == operator

Comment: for some reason, even with that, the whitespace character is stil not being remove. I even tried replacing it with other values from my stack, to no luck, its the same result. Is there any other way of implementing this aside from what I did?. I mean, other declarations?

Comment: `while(myQ.peek().trim().equals("")){ myQ.poll(); } `

Comment: Why don't you avoid pushing whitespace in the first place?

Comment: Gene, yes, I tried doing that. But to no avail, much like this one that seem obvious to solve but rather tricky to implement, I can't quite remove it before pushing it to stack. So finally decided  to just push it to stack and remove it if its a whitespace(my delimiter), afterall, I could individually remove them since I have at least 3 delimiters that should be removed like tab, space and newline and many more, and would seem easy in my assumption since its within stack and queues instead of implementing it in an if else or switch statements. Unless there's much clean and easier way out of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gene is right, you'd better check if a string is empty before pushing it into a queue (or stack). If you already have a queue (or stack) with empty string, as in your case, you can use `Queue` (resp. `Stack`)'s `removeIf(Predicate)` method and do the following,

```
myQ.removeIf(s -> s.trim().isEmpty());
```

Both `Queue` and `Stack` provided by `java.util` package have this method.

Comment: I tried doing the checking of an empty string before pushing it to stack, but to no avail. I just messed up my code. So I decided to push it to stack and then  just pop/remove it if its empty or is a whitespace character which would make the code seem shorter in my assumption with less the if and else and also, I may be able to remove that part of the code should I decide to add it later as part of a lexeme.

BTW, thx alot, that's just the code I'm exactly looking for and finally worked. Never encountered that in my searches even in here since most are pertaining to strings and not stacks.

Answer (score 1):

The below code should work for you:

```
while(myQ.peek().trim().equals("")) { 
    myQ.poll();
}
```

Comment: that didn't worked still for removing the whitespace characters. IDK too, by reading it, it seems correct, but when running it, it doesn't do the job. What seemed to be an obvious solution is really hard at all. hehe. BTW, thx for the help. really appreaciate it. :)